# iTextSharp - Modify additional metadata in PDF

Tags: c#, itext

There are a lot of `iTextSharp` examples out there showing how to append metadata like "Title", "Author", "Keywords" to an existing PDF using `PdfStamper.MoreInfo` dictionary ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380837/set-metadata-in-itextsharp)), and I've successfully managed to do this.

But is there a way to set properties that Adobe Reader calls "Additional Metadata" that are visible when you click "Document Properties" -> "Additional metadata"? These properties include "Description", "Author title", "Copyright status", "Copyright notice" and some more. Are there some dictionary keys in `PdfStamper.MoreInfo` that represent these properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText5 does not expose the additional data in `PdfStamper#MoreInfo`. It is however possible to retrieve the metadata containing  using `PdfReader#XmpMetaData` and to set it using `PdfDocument#XmpMetaData` or `PdfStamper#XmpMetaData`.

the metadata is returned and set as a `byte[]`, so you'll have to handle the translation/generation from and to yourself.

In iText7, the process is mostly the same, but handled through the `PdfDocument` class instead (since it is a wrapper for a `PdfReader` and `PdfWriter` object.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not about writing that data but [how to read it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930045/3227403). It may give you some hints on how to write it, too.

Answer (score -1):

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 72, 108, 180);
doc.AddTitle("Hello World example");
doc.AddSubject("This is an Example 4 of Chapter 1 of Book 'iText in Action'");
doc.AddKeywords("Metadata, iTextSharp 5.4.4, Chapter 1, Tutorial");
doc.AddCreator("iTextSharp 5.4.4");
doc.AddAuthor("Debopam Pal");
doc.AddHeader("Nothing", "No Header");
```

For more details and features [Click Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in)

Comment: Nope. (1) I asked about modifying additional metadata, while you're showing standard metadata sample (2) I asked about modifying an existing document, and your code creates a new document